# TortoiseGit / Winforms: Are Commits Local to Git Clone?

Tags: winforms, git, svn, github, tortoisegit

I have not seen an answer an Stackoverflow yet.

Scenario:
- I make changes within a project with source files retrieved through Git Clone
- commits are done
- pulls and merging are partially done

At this point, I decide that merging has some challenges.
Is is possible to do a fresh Git Clone, make the same changes there, redo the commits and any merging if needed with the final push? In other words, if I redo using this second Git Clone, will any residual be left from the first Git Clone and its associated commits, pulling and merging? Are all commits, etc. just local?

Thanks. Any answers appreciated. I am working in a team and do not want to cause any ripples with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In other words, if I redo using this second Git Clone, will any residual be left from the first Git Clone and its associated commits, pulling and merging?

No, you won't see anything from the first repo.

> Are all commits, etc. just local?

Yes. Local to your local repo: as long as those commits aren't pushed somewhere (or fetched), they remain only in said local repo.
If you create a second repo, cloning the same upstream repo as the first one, it won't see anything done in the first local repo.